# How can intercept base field validation before own validation

Tags: python, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

In my DRF model i have next field:

```
myfield = ArrayField(
    models.CharField(max_length=7, blank=True, null=True),
    blank=True,
    null=True
)
```

and in serializer i'm writing function for validate this myfield:

```
def validate_myfield(self, value):  # validate only for this myfield (value = field value from request)
    **some validations**

    return value
```

but if in request field `myfield = "string"/integer_value` or etc i get error: `Expected a list of items but got type \"int\".` from base field validation(from rest serializer).

how can intercept this error before myfield validation (if in request field not array of strings, validation does not start) and print my error message?

Answer (score 0):

in case you want to check type of class type.isinstance is very useful

```
def validate_myfield(self, value):  # validate only for this myfield (value = field value from request)
    assert  isinstance(value,list )
    # Your code here when the assertion pass
    to excluse string,and it
    assert not isinstance(value,(int,str))
    return value
```

Comment: A type error will appear before the function starts

Comment: A little incorrectly described the problem, edited it